# Lock on a key in a hazelcast cluster

Tags: caching, hazelcast, jcache, jsr107

I am writing a distributed application using Hazelcast(JCache standard) for caching.

I have an use case where I should put a lock on specific key in a cluster to prevent from calls during updating.

1. thread1: get item1 for a config change(put a lock)
2. thread2: get item1 for an update.
3. thread2: put item1 with update and a new timestamp.
4. thread1: put item1 with an old value and timestamp

I know EhCache has something very similar, it's called acquireReadLockOnKey(Object key).

How can I achieve that kind of lock using JCache and/or Hazelcast?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to use CAS (Compare And Set) alike operations (like ConcurrentMap::replace) and utilize an optimistic locking pattern which is not a real lock in itself.

```
while(true) {
  // Get the old value
  T oldValue = map.get(key);
  // Create the new value based on the "known old state"
  T newValue = createNewValue(oldValue);
  // Try to atomically exchange to the new value, if oldValue is still valid
  if (map.replace(key, oldValue, newValue) break;
  // If oldValue isn't valid anymore, retry
}
```

In most situation where there is no high contention rate, this is the best alternativ over real locking. It solves most of the read-modify-write problems and doesn't need EntryProcessor classes to be deployed/available on the cluster.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Entry Processor](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#implementing-entryprocessor) which performs update operations on cache entries in an atomic and lock-free manner.

Comment: Are talking about EntryProcessor from JCache? Does it work properly in a distributed cache?

Comment: In our project we use Entry Processors for Hazelcast IMap and we haven't faced concurrency issues.Entry Processor is good way to mutate data in a distributed environment. Entry processor is performed on key owners, it allows to achieve atomicity 
 and avoid sending data through network.

Comment: Both answers have merit; if you have low contention, you can go for CAS as described above. Otherwise you can use JCache `EntryProcessor`, [its contract](https://github.com/jsr107/jsr107spec/blob/37937a43c66b986dbfc0aa8291c8f10975b26dc0/src/main/java/javax/cache/processor/EntryProcessor.java#L26-L32) guarantees it will be executed atomically on a key. You just need to make sure your `EntryProcessor` code is deployed on all members of the Hazelcast cluster.